# theme theme-name doesn't have "theme" setting for customizing my theme in sphinx?

Tags: themes, customization, python-sphinx

I want to create my own theme--`mytheme` for python-sphinx.

```
tree project
project
├── build
├── make.bat
├── Makefile
├── mytheme
│   ├── static
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── theme.conf
└── source
    └── conf.py
```

Content in theme.conf:

```
cat  project/mytheme/theme.conf
[theme]
inherit = default
stylesheet = style.css
```

Conent in `project/source/conf.py`

```
cat project/source/conf.py
def setup(app):
    app.add_stylesheet('static/style.css')
    app.add_html_theme('mytheme', os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

html_theme = 'mytheme'  
html_theme_path = ['.']
```

Now let's make all my *.rst file in source.

```
cd project
make html
Running Sphinx v2.4.4
loading pickled environment... done

Theme error:
theme 'mytheme' doesn't have "theme" setting
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'html' failed
make: *** [html] Error 2
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: It looks like you followed every step in the docs https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/theming.html, except for `setup.py`. Also the docs don't mention how to install your theme, which might be an omission. After configuring your `setup.py`, try `pip install -e ."[docs]"` to install your package in editable mode, then try to use it. I have never done this, but it makes sense to install your package in order to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use two mutually exclusive approaches - using local theme from filesystem, and at the same time register theme as it is done in themes distributed as Python PyPI package.

If you want a theme to be a part of the Sphinx project, good place for such project-specific themes is `_themes/` in the directory with conf.py, and set `html_theme = "mytheme"` and `html_theme_path = ["_themes"]` in your conf.py.

```
_themes/
    mytheme/
        static/
            css/
                main.css
        theme.conf
        layout.html
conf.py
index.rst
second.rst
third.rst
...
```

(borrowed from https://blog.documatt.com/sphinx-theming/themes.html#project-specific-themes)

Completely delete block

```
def setup(app):
    app.add_stylesheet('static/style.css')
    app.add_html_theme('mytheme', os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

`add_html_theme()` it is for themes distributed as a package. `add_stylesheet()` is to add additional (not replace existing) stylesheet. Themes main stylesheet is in their theme.conf `stylesheet` option.

The last issue I see in your example is your theme inherit from `default` theme. It works, it looks it's an old name for `classic` theme (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/theming.html#builtin-themes), but use its official name - `classic`.